# How do I use the FutureBuilder correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView` where I want to Display a boolean I read via my dbhelper from my SQFLite DB of my app.
Since reading and writing are asynchronous, I needed a bit to find out about the `FutureBuilder`.
The DB-Helper Method is:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getItem(String tableName, String id) async {
    Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $colId = $id ORDER BY $colCategory DESC, $colName DESC");
    Map<String, dynamic> singleMap = result[0];
    return singleMap;
  }
```

My extracting Method is:

```
 Future<bool> isObtainedDB(Settings settings) async {
    var map = await _dbHelper.getItem(_dbHelper.tblSavedata, id);
    //var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    bool obtained = map[_dbHelper.colObtained];
    return obtained;
  }
```

I am stuck where I am trying to wrap the builder around my Checkbox for proof of concept:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: isObtainedDB(settings),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(localization.obtained),
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              value: isObtainedDB(settings),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setObtained(settings, value);
              });}),
```

How can I now use the boolean from isObtainedDB in my CheckBoxListTile?

Comment: Since you're getting everything at once, it makes sense to wrap the ListView with the FutureBuilder, and then you can iterate over the elements to draw your ListTile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value from the future is saved to `snapshot.data` in the builder function, so if a boolean is returned from `isObtainedDB(settings)`, you need to access it like this: `snapshot.data` (holds the value of asynchronous function)

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: isObtainedDB(settings),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text(localization.obtained),
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      value: snapshot.data, //true or false
      onChanged: (value) {
        setObtained(settings, value);
      }
    );
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I use 5 seconds delay to simulate `getItem` 
Step 1: To avoid Future builder rebuilds unnecessarily https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426#issuecomment-414047398

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _future = isObtainedDB(settings);
    super.initState();
  }
 ... 
body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
```

Step 2: Check `ConnectionState`

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.none:
          return Text('none');
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
```

Step 3 : Use `snapshot.data`

```
CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text("localization.obtained"),
                    controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                    value: snapshot.data,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<bool> _future;
  Settings settings = Settings();

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getItem(String tableName, String id) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () {});
    /*Database db = await this.db;
    var result = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE $colId = $id ORDER BY $colCategory DESC, $colName DESC");
    Map<String, dynamic> singleMap = result[0];*/
    return Future.value(null);
  }

  Future<bool> isObtainedDB(Settings settings) async {
    var map = await getItem("_dbHelper.tblSavedata", "id");
    //var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    bool obtained = true; //map[_dbHelper.colObtained];
    return obtained;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = isObtainedDB(settings);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return CheckboxListTile(
                        title: Text("localization.obtained"),
                        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                        value: snapshot.data,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          //setObtained(settings, value);
                        });
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}

class Settings {}
```